# How to create a network diagram on Python, given an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, networkx

[image of objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSA3o.jpg)

How would you create a clear network diagram, with curved arrows from an adjacency matrix **(pandas dtaframe)** in Python.

I have tried 'networkx', but seems quite complex and difficult to customize. Is there a program that is more simple, for the objective I describe in the image attached [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSA3o.jpg).

The goal is to have a diagram showing what machines feed eachother, in a manufacturing process flow?

Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Which format is your adjacency matrix in? A Pandas DataFrame? A NumPy array?

Comment: Recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow, but I am pretty sure you can find Python packages for [this kind of graphs](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%20%20%22A%22%20-%3E%20%22Tool%22%20%20%5B%20label%3D%22100%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%22Tool%22%20-%3E%20%22A%22%20%20%5B%20label%3D%2220%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%22B%22%20-%3E%20%22Tool%22%20%20%5B%20label%3D%2250%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%22Tool%22%20-%3E%20%22C%22%20%20%5B%20label%3D%222000%22%20%5D%0A%7D%0A).

Comment: I once used `G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(adjacency_matrix, create_using=nx.DiGraph())`

Answer (score 0):

Networkx will be enough for your task. You can easily create and save graphs. Here is a quick example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_weighted_edges_from([("Tool", "A", 80), ("A", "Tool", 100), ("B", "Tool", 50), ("Tool", "C", 2000)])
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True, font_weight='normal')
plt.savefig("your_graph.png")
```

Currently this example doesn't display weight of edges and curvy arrows but I am sure it's configurable. For more info just check [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html). Hope my answer will be heplfull

Comment: this is great! Thanks Neistow.

One question - how would you convert a .csv matrix into the form you have given here:

`graph.add_weighted_edges_from([("Tool", "A", 80), ("A", "Tool", 100), ("B", "Tool", 50), ("Tool", "C", 2000)])`

Comment: There is built in module for working with csv. You'll probably need to make a loop where in each iteration will be added new edge.